# Get current application physical path within Application_Start

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm not able to get the current physical path within Application_Start using

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath
```

because there is no **Request** object at that time.

How else can I get the physical path?

Comment: Related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10951599/465053).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
 protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     string path = Server.MapPath("/");
     //or 
     string path2 = Server.MapPath("~");
     //depends on your application needs

 }
```

Answer (score 33):

I created a website with ASP.Net WebForms where you can see the result of using all forms mentioned in previous responses from a site in Azure.

http://wfserverpaths.azurewebsites.net/

Summary:

---

```
Server.MapPath("/") => D:\home\site\wwwroot\
```

---

```
Server.MapPath("~") => D:\home\site\wwwroot\
```

---

```
HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath => D:\home\site\wwwroot\
```

---

```
HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath => /
```

---

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory => D:\home\site\wwwroot\
```

---

```
HostingEnvironment.MapPath("/") => D:\home\site\wwwroot\
```

---

```
HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~") => D:\home\site\wwwroot\
```

Comment: How can I get: \\myserver\inetpub\wwwroot\myfolder instead of C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myfolder....

Comment: Select an option above and write this small code:
`var pathComponents = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.Split(':'); pathComponents[0] = @"\\" + System.Environment.MachineName; var resultPath = string.Join("", pathComponents);`

Answer (score 23):

You can also use

```
HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath
```

Comment: For the physical path, you'd actually want `HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath` which "Gets the physical drive path of the application directory for the application hosted in the current application domain."  `HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath` actually gets a virtual path such as "/MyApp".  Either way, using HttpRuntime is the best way to get the application physical path, because it's available in every context, including static contexts even before an `HttpApplication` object is available.

Comment: The other solutions posted here require an `HttpServerUtility` instance to be accessed through the `Server` property, which is available only within the context of an application event like "Application_Start" or within an active web request.

Comment: `HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath`

Answer (score 17):

Use [`Server.MapPath("~")`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This works better than  Server.MapPath("/"); because the path of the web application might not be the same as the root application one.

Comment: And `HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath` works better than any of these, because it works in any context including static contexts, whereas all other options require an `HttpServerUtility` instance to be accessed through the `Server` property, which is available only within the context of an application event like "Application_Start" or within an active web request.

Answer (score 10):

You can use this code:

`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`

Answer (score 5):

**Best choice is using**

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

because it's in the system namespace and there is **no dependency** to **system.web**

this way your code will be more **portable**

Answer (score 3):

use below code

`server.mappath()` in asp.net

`application.startuppath` in c# windows application

Answer (score 3):

There is also the static
    HostingEnvironment.MapPath

Answer (score 2):

`System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`

This will give you the running directory of your application. This even works for web applications. Afterwards, you can reach your file.

Answer (score 1):

There's, however, slight difference among all these options which

I found out that

If you do

```
    string URL = Server.MapPath("~");
```

or

```
    string URL = Server.MapPath("/");
```

or

```
    string URL = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath;
```

your URL will display resources in your link like this:

```
    "file:///d:/InetPUB/HOME/Index/bin/Resources/HandlerDoc.htm"
```

But if you want your URL to show only virtual path not the resources location, you should do

```
    string URL = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath;
```

then, your URL is displaying a virtual path to your resources as below

```
    "http://HOME/Index/bin/Resources/HandlerDoc.htm"
```